# How to span rows in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to achieve a layout like below in Bootstrap but am having a difficult time with it. I feel dumb asking this but it's my first time using Bootstrap and I couldn't find a similar example on here.

Thanks!

[image]

I thought maybe something like this, but div C clears div B and ends up way too far down the page.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      A
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      B
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      C
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add your code..

Comment: Which one are you trying to achieve? The left or right? or both on the same page?

Comment: Left is mobile view right is desktop view i guess

Comment: Oops sorry, code added! Yes, left is mobile, right is desktop!

Comment: @ridgek for a pure Bootstrap solution check my answer below using pull-left and pull-right to avoid the unwanted white space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a pure bootstrap solution you need to add `col-xs-12` to make it 100% on mobiles and `col-sm-6` to make it 50% on desktop. The add `pull-left` and `pull-right` to avoid the B panel to clear and move C below everything

```css
.bg-danger, .bg-primary {
  height: 200px;
}
.bg-success {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bg-danger pull-left"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bg-success pull-right"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bg-primary pull-left"></div>
  </div>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Click full page to see the difference

Comment: Thank you @phobia82! This is exactly what I needed! <3

Answer (score 0):

Here we have an explanation about the grid system.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The page is split in half with the two outer columns "col-sm-6", with one of these columns containing two inner columns that span it's entire width

Comment: Thanks but this puts C below B on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution if you want essentailly the green box to come in between.

Check this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/rRUHxGWT1N) for responsive-ness check.

Snippet here:

```css
.something {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="something bg-danger"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="something bg-success"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="something bg-primary"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is another example where the Green box will come below the rest two boxes..:

```css
.something {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div clas="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="something bg-danger"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="something bg-primary"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="something bg-success"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the green box does need to go in the middle. The problem here is that the blue one clears the height of the green one; leaving unwanted white space between the blue and red boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps..:)

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><!--div for the left side abc pattern starts-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          "standing a"
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          "standing b - adjust the height of this block"
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          "standing c"
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- div for the left side abc pattern ends -->
    <div class="col-sm-6"><!-- div for the right side abc pattern starts -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              "block a"
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              "block b"
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          "block c"
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- div for the right side abc pattern ends -->
  </div><!-- row closed here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all this work but the left side is actually a mobile view and the right side a desktop view!

Comment: then you can just have the right side block code and increase the column accordingly. Ignore the left side block code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Pure **CSS Flexbox** for this.

Have a look at the snippet below (*use full screen for desktop mode*):

```css
.box-holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  height: 280px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  align-self: flex-start;
  order: 1;
  background: green;
  height: 240px;
  margin: 0;
}

.c {
  background: blue;
}

/* On Mobiles */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .box-holder {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
    
  .b {
    align-self: center !important;
    order: 0;
    margin: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box-holder">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but I strongly prefer to let Bootstrap do my div size calculations if possible.

Comment: @ridgek You can include this with bootstrap's `col-*-*` classes but you need to put some extra effort by overwriting the bootstrap's `float` etc. properties.